# c# outlook SendEventHandler abrindo objeto apenas uma vez

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, interop

Na minha aplicação utilizo SendEventHandler do outlook para capturar o clique no botão "Enviar" do email no outlook e abrir uma tela para cadastro de observação referente ao email que foi enviado.

Tenho a classe principal onde gero os emails:

```
public partial class PendenciaConsulta : UserControl
{
   EmailEnviado emailEnviado = null;

   private void btnEnviarEmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach(string grupo in ListaGrupo)
       {
          emailEnviado = new EmailEnviado();

          emailEnviado.ListaPendenciaId = listaPendencia.Where(p=>p.ClienteGrupo == grupo).Select(p=>p.PendenciaId).ToList();
          emailEnviado.PendenciaConsulta = this;

          //Preparo o body
          // ....

          MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

          ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(emailEnviado.EmailEnviadoEvent);
          ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Close += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(emailEnviado.EmailCanceladoEvent);

          mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

          mailItem.HTMLBody = body.ToString();
          mailItem.Display();
       }
   }
}
```

E a classe secundária:

```
/// <summary>
/// Classe criada para poder receber a lista de ids de pendencias para ser tratadas no event.
/// </summary>
public class EmailEnviado
{
    public List<int> ListaPendenciaId { get; set; }
    public PendenciaConsulta PendenciaConsulta { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construtor para receber os parametros necessários
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listaPendenciaId"></param>
    /// <param name="pendenciaConsulta"></param>
    /// <param name="isITM"></param>
    /// <param name="isRecepcao"></param>
    public EmailEnviado(List<int> listaPendenciaId, PendenciaConsulta pendenciaConsulta, MailItem mailItem)
    {
        this.ListaPendenciaId = listaPendenciaId;
        this.PendenciaConsulta = pendenciaConsulta;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Criado pois os booleans não estavam sendo enviador através do construtor
    /// </summary>
    public EmailEnviado()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captura o evento se o usuário fechou sem enviar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Cancel"></param>
    public void EmailCanceladoEvent(ref bool Cancel)
    {

    }

    public void EmailEnviadoEvent(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inicio email enviado event");
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inicio Dispatcher");

            System.Windows.Window historicoEmailCadastro = new     System.Windows.Window
            {
                Title = "Cadastro de Histórico de Email",
                Content = new HistoricoEmailCadastro(ListaPendenciaId,     PendenciaConsulta),
                Width = 270,
                Height = 260,
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
                Topmost = true,
                WindowStartupLocation =    WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Criou a window");

            historicoEmailCadastro.ShowDialog();

            if (StatusId == 4)
            {
                PendenciaController pendenciaControllerEmail = new     PendenciaController();
                 pendenciaControllerEmail.PendenciaStatusAtualizarPorPendenciaId(ListaPendenciaId, StatusId, optionalData: true);
                PendenciaConsulta.PendenciaStatusAtualizarPorPendenciaId(ListaPendenciaId, StatusId, optionalData: true);
            }

            else
            {
                PendenciaController pendenciaControllerEmail = new     PendenciaController();
                pendenciaControllerEmail.PendenciaStatusAtualizarPorPendenciaId(ListaPendenciaId, StatusId);
                PendenciaConsulta.PendenciaStatusAtualizarPorPendenciaId(ListaPendenciaId, StatusId);

            }

            PendenciaConsulta.PesquisarOffLine();
        });
    }
}
```

O problema está sendo que só é executado o event no primeiro email enviado.
Ex: gero dois emails diferentes, em um objeto "emailEnviado" a ListaPendenciaId fica com 11 itens, no segundo email a lista fica com 4 items.

Quando envio o email seja o primeiro ou seja o segundo, o objeto vem com as propriedades corretas. Se envio primeiro o primeiro email com a lista de 11 objetos ele vem correto e se envio primeiro o segundo email ele vem a lista de 4 objetos corretos. Mas o evento "EmailEnviadoEvent" só é disparado na primeira vez que envio um email e os demais que estão abertos e envio depois não disparam o evento.

Comment: Tentei reproduzir o problema na minha máquina mas faltou entender melhor qual a funcionalidade você está querendo desenvolver. Poderia detalhar o contexto da aplicação e da funcionalidade específica?

Comment: Dentro do evento "EmailEnviadoEvent" eu chamo a tela "HistoricoEmailCadastro" que serve para fazer o cadastro de uma observação. 

Contexto: 

1 - Tela de consulta de pendências.
     Essa tela lista todas as pendências que os analistas devem cobrar dos clientes.

Comment: 2 - Envio de email:
    Os analistas selecionam as pendências que querem fazer cobranças e clicam em um botão para gerar os emails automaticamente. Esses emails são gerados pelo grupo de empresa, então o analista pode selecionar 20 pendências e serem gerados 3 emails por grupos diferentes (Grupo 1 - 10 pendências, Grupo 2 - 3 pendências, Grupo 4 - 7 pendências).

Comment: 3 - O analista cadastra a obsevação utilizando a tela "HistoricoEmailCadastro" a cada email enviado.

Comment: Hoje eu gero apenas uma observação independente de quantos emails são gerados, pois crio apenas um objeto "EmailEnviado" onde tenho todos os ids das pendências que ele gerou os emails. O objetivo é que para cada email enviado ele abra uma janela da tela "HistoricoEmailCadastro"